# Texture not loading glActiveTexture

Tags: c, opengl

I have been having some issues trying to get my texture to be displayed. I am attempting to initialize textures, then use glActiveTexture to use them in my opengl display.

I first get declare these textures via:

```
// Texture identifiers
    GLuint texture0, texture1, texture2, texture3, texture4, texture5, texture6;
```

Then during my initialization I try and create the textures via the following code:

```
//Load the active textures for each of our textures
    //Bind them, to be referenced later
    glGenTextures(1, &texture0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1000, 
            1000,0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
      ceiling_tile);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 500, 
            500,0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
      floor_tile);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 64, 
                 64,0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                 lamp_color);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture3);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture3);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 500, 
            500,0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
      total_black);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture4);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture4);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 500, 
            500,0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
      flower_texture);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture5);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture5);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 500, 
            500,0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
      dinosaur_texture);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture6);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE6);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture6);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 500, 
            500,0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
      chair_texture);
```

and then during my opengl display function, when I want to activate each one of these textures, I run:

```
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+3); glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture3);
'''
```

However when I do all of this no texture is loading into them. I do not know if I am calling all of these correctly? Any Ideas?

I have tried moving around the glActiveTextures to be stuff like glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTUREX) , where X equals 1-6.

Comment: opengl texture sampling uses mipmap by default. you should either deactivate mipmap (glTexParameter) sampling or load/generate mipmaps (glGenerateMipmap).

Comment: First, you don't need to activate texture slots when uploading your texture. Second, why are you activating from `GL_TEXTURE0+3` (==`GL_TEXTURE3`) when rendering?. Third, what is `bind textures to be referenced later? You will have to bind each texture when using it because each texture binding overrides the previous one. Finally, provide more information (code), like your render loop or wherever you are using the textures.

Comment: do I deactivate mipmap in my display function, or in my initialization when I create all of the textures?

Comment: nadir, I removed the activateTexture calls in the initialization function. I removed the 0+ in the rendering, making it GL_TEXTURE3. However I am still not seeing my texture being displayed. 
I setup the following variables in my render display:
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

Comment: I tried disabling the mipmap both in the initialization and the render via the following line: 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

That still did not work.